# SwiftUI @Observable does not track changes in parent class properties to update the view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

This is the model data

```swift
class A {
    var p: Int = 1

    func update() {
        self.p = self.p + 1
    }
}


@Observable
class BStore: A {
    // nothing
}
```

This is the view

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var bStore = BStore()

    var body: some View {
        CountView()
            .environment(bStore)
    }
}

struct CountView: View {
    @Environment(BStore.self) private var bStore

    var body: some View {
        Text("count: \(bStore.p)")
            .onTapGesture(perform: {
                bStore.update()
            })
    }
}
```

`bStore.p` changes correctly, but the view is not updated; if `class A` adds `@Observable`, the view will update normally

I have 2 questions:

1. Under the current design and `class A` does not use `@Observable`, how to make the view update correctly? If not, then how to design it? The premise is that `class A` cannot use `@Observable`, because `class A` not only serves the view, `@Observable class BStore` is equivalent to `class A`'s agent serving views only
2. `bStore` inherits `class A` and has all its properties and methods, and uses `@Observable`, but why are the parent class properties of `bStore` not tracked for changes, causing the view to not change?

Comment: Why don't you wanna use @Observable on class A? If you do that you could even remove it from class B and also avoid using State for bStore.

Comment: @MatBuompy Class A is more like an sdk, providing an api to be used elsewhere; So that class A can also be used in view and keep clean, hence `@Observable class BStore: A`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Observable` is a *macro*. When it expands, it finds all the stored properties in your class and adds special getters and setters for each of them.

In addition to returning and setting the properties' values, these getters and setters also notify a `ObservationRegistrar` (also generated by the macro) that these properties are accessed/modified. Using this, SwiftUI can find dependencies of the view and track changes correctly.

If you apply `@Observable` to a subclass, there is no stored properties declared there, so `@Observable` doesn't generate any of those getters/setters that notify the `ObservationRegistrar`. Macros operate on the *textual* content of your code only - they cannot go to the super class and inspect what stored properties are there.

If you really want `BStore` observable but not `A`, you will need to override `p`, and add the getters and setters that `@Observable` *would have generated*.

```
@Observable
class BStore: A {
    override var p: Int {
        get {
            access(keyPath: \.p)
            return super.p
        }
        set {
            withMutation(keyPath: \.p) {
                super.p = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would need to do this for each property you want observed.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand why macros can't check superclass properties; The reason for rejecting `@Observable` in `A` is that `A` is more like an sdk, providing an api to be used elsewhere; So that class A can also be used in view and keep clean, hence `@Observable class BStore: A`

Comment: @JoeLiu You mean `A` is from a third party library, and you can't change its code?

Comment: `class A` will be a third party library that can be used as model data for views but also provide apis elsewhere, such as native apis for react-native apps. So I worry about side effects when `@Observable` is not used as model data

Comment: @JoeLiu That shouldn't be a problem. I don't think `@Observable` would affect that. That said, perhaps you should follow the single responsibility principle and *not* have a class that does two things. How about splitting `A` up?

Comment: Now it can do exactly two things; if split it into two class, the only difference is whether we have @Observable or not.

Comment: @JoeLiu What is your point? Do you still have questions about this that I did not address in my answer?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can't think of A better design for this situation. For now,A use @Observable and remove B